# asp.net Global.asax Application_Start

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with framework 3.5.

I have created an asp.net website from scratch and I have added an Global.asax to the project.

On global.asax, there is the Application_Start event. I have placed a breakpoint on that event and started debugging the website and I noticed it hits the breakpoint. But if I closed the website and start debuggin again the breakpoint is not hit. If I stop the ASP.NET Development Server and start debugging again, then the breakpoint is hit again.

So, reading on this article:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/5771721

it says: **The Application_Init and Application_Start events are fired once when the application is first started.**

So I'm guessing that means when the application is first started with the server. I guess the same thing would happen with IIS, one would need to restart the IIS so that the Application_Start is fired again.

If this is the case with global.asax, then I can't use it.

The thing is I want a piece of code to be executed every time a specific page on my website is accessed.

In order to accomplish this I would need to put that code on my master page or in the specific page of the site?

Thanks...

Comment: Can you tell what that code does? Do you want to run it each time a user opens browser and navigates to your site?

Comment: The code at the moment does nothing. As I said, I have just started the project from nothing and I was just testing the event and testing when is being fired. And yes, I want the code to run each time the user opens the browser.

Comment: What if user never closes the browser (my browser is open for days sometimes)?

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. What I meant is I want the code to run each time the user visits a page within the website.

Comment: @trek if this is the case, you should update your question.

Comment: ok. I have updated it now.

Comment: Now it matters whether you are using web forms or MVC.  Which are you using?

Comment: @trek any page or a specific page?

Comment: And is for a specific page.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Application_BeginRequest` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: as the question stands now, I'm not sure this will work.  The OP is now asking for behaviour only on a specific page. ;)

Comment: @DavinTryon not sure, for me it reads as _any page_ — but I have asked to clarify this anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, is to put the desired code on the Page_Load event of the specific page in which the behavior is required.

But also, if it's something that is required for all pages it could be placed on the master page Page_Load event so that it fires every time any page on the site is accessed.

If I'm wrong with this answer please correct me. Thanks!